# Laravel - go back after logout

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have some troubles with killing the session when doing logout in Laravel. What I`m doing in my Logout method is

```
Auth::logout(); 
Session::flush();

return View::make(..);
```

So what is my problem. After I logout and click to "back" in the browser, it gets me back in the page I was, without asking for login. How can I kill the session, so that after logout and going back to ask me for login again ?

Comment: What happens when you refresh the page after pressing the back button?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters
You need to filter that page and reroute to login

Comment: Are you using route filters?

Comment: Refreshing the page or trying to access any element after logout causes login screen. I think Mauricio`s suggestion will work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up to my previous comment, Laravel contains a default filter called 'auth' that checks if user is authenticated and redirects to the login view if he isn't.

You simply need to add the filter to the route

```
Route::get('your route here', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    return 'normal route behavior here'
}));
```

Comment: im still stuck on this, I dont know why but my problem still persist. I have done same as yours.

Comment: ahw nevermind its working now, all of my routes are under a group and I added another group for logout nested in to all my routes.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to:

```
Auth::logout(); 
Session::flush();
Redirect::back();
```

or..

```
Redirect::route('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click to the previeus botton in the browser it just make a view to the previeus page but no request and response to or from the server.

But if you want to revok this action use javascript like :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You must login"; };
```